# How to customize height of a React native TextInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I changed the height of my TextInput but on android the input itself stays in the middle. How can I change it so the text start on the top of the box? [image: This is how it looks on android]

```
textInput: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "rgba(199,218,228,1)",
        borderRadius: 8,
        height: 312,
        paddingTop: 8.21,
        paddingBottom: 8.21,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        fontFamily: "FiraSans-Regular",
        fontSize: 14,
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textAlignVertical` should help you out here, the component's default behavior is to center the text within the input.

If you add:

```
textAlignVertical: 'top'
```

to your style it should bring the input to the beginning. The information is kinda hidden in the docs under the `multiline` prop: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#multiline

> multiline
>
> If true, the text input can be multiple lines. The default value is
> false. It is important to note that this aligns the text to the top on
> iOS, and centers it on Android. Use with textAlignVertical set to top
> for the same behavior in both platforms.